# How do i make html img src display after clicking input submit via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi everyone i need help with making an `<img src="https://i.ibb.co/QCMtktm/ns.gif" height="16px"width="16px" />` display in input submit running with javascript,
so what the code does it to change the value "Login" to "Logging in" when clicked, so i want the img to show just beside the "Logging in" when i click the submit

e.g

```
<html>
<form class="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" method="post" data-action"">
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</html>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.ajaxform').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let form = $(this);
            let formData = form.serializeArray(),
                submit = form.find('[type="submit"]'),
                action = form.attr('data-action')

            submit.prop('disabled', true);
            submit.val('Logging in'+<img src="https://i.ibb.co/QCMtktm/ns.gif" height="16px"width="16px" />);

});
    });

</script>
```

Note: please this code is wrong help me correct it, and also don't use button tags only input thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you are trying to add a `<img>` to html `<input type="submit"/>` but `input` is not a **container tag**,so its not possible to add an  tag inside it using the code provided above.

So there are many ways of fixing it(the method 2 is the easy method):

1. using `<input type="image" src=""/>` here you can change the src to the image you need after the action.
   instead of

```html
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
```

```html
<input type=image src=https://i.ibb.co/QCMtktm/ns.gif alt="Submit feedback" id="submit" value="login">
```

But here you cant add the text normally so you need to create a gif that has the text("Logging in") in itself.So `method 2` is the easy way.

2. using css and setting the background to the required gif/image.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.ajaxform').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this);
    let formData = form.serializeArray(),
    submit = form.find('[type="submit"]'),
    action = form.attr('data-action')

    submit.prop('disabled', true);
    submit.val('Logging in');
    submit.css({
      'background': 'url("https://i.ibb.co/QCMtktm/ns.gif") no-repeat',
      'background-size': '25% 100%',
      'text-align':'left',
      'background-position': 'right center',
    });
  });
});
```

```css
input{
  border:1px solid #222;
  width:128px;
  height:32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <form class="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" method="post" data-action="">
      <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note:Here instead of 16x16 gif size i used 32x32 px.(for more visibility).Here i have added the background image of the submit button to the loading `gif` and positioned it on right by adding css using jQuery.